# How to measure how long an element took to load?

Tags: javascript, html, analytics

For analytics, I'm interested in logging the details of time taken to load various components of a webpage. I'm not interested in any of the 3rd-party analytics available already.

More about the page:

- There are no iFrames.
- Each component is in a `<div></div>` of its own.
- Most components don't have images in them.

What I've tried so far:

1. onload event. This seems to work only for the `<body>`
2. addEventListener - for 'load' event, it doesn't work. :(
3. A new tag to do this, via web components, but that isn't supported on IE8. Again, :(
4. `<script>logDivLoadedDetails();</script>` - when strategically placed, works. But this makes the code ugly! And I do not want to add this to every div.

Is there a way for me to gather the time it took to load a particular div?

Also, some pointers on how to trigger a script on an element load will help me move along the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand what is your issue with the `onload` event? `addEventListener('load', callback);` and `window.onload = callback;` does or less the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't onload work only for `<body>` not `<div>`

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense in the context of how pages are loaded. For example, item 4 doesn't really give you the info you think it's giving you.

Comment: Your divs are usually in your body...

Comment: You mean the time for one particular div in your body to load? Independently from the remaining of the page?

Comment: @Quentin Roy - Agreed. A simple use-case - my page has a lot of widgets. I can't meaningfully use the latency logs of the body the widget loads.

Comment: @Quentin Roy - Ah! Yes, for 'You mean the time for one particular div in ...'

Comment: Regardless, if you really need detailed timing info, in their respective developer tools, Firefox has a Performance tab, Chrome has a Timeline tab, and Edge has a Performance tab.

Comment: @Ouroborus  - Please can you explain? 
Item 4 - If I have a script tag placed strategically(At the start & end of an element), I can always perform a diff in the time & log the same. But, I do not want to do this.

Comment: @Ouroborus - 'Firefox has a Performance tab, Chrome has a Timeline tab, and Edge'. But, I won't be able to access these details when the page is rendered on a client's browser. If I can gather this somehow is JS, I can then extend it to send these details to server via ajax.

Comment: @user657592 It doesn't actually measure that. It measures the time it takes the HTML parser to get from the first bit of code to the next. Any images in the div won't be included in that timing as they aren't necessary in order for the javascript to run.

Comment: @Ouroborus  - What doesn't measure what? Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Please explain that part again.

Comment: As you put it, there is no `load` event for divs. Even more importantly, your browser will render your page as a whole, it does not really make sense to separate parts of it. If you want to measure the impact of a particular div, I would suggest comparing the rendering time without it and the loading time with it, or to use your browser's profiling tool (if it gives you such info). I cannot see any other way.

Comment: @user657592 Your item 4 doesn't measure what you think it's measuring.

Comment: @Ouroborus - Oh? Okay, I'll research more into that!

Comment: Check the developer tools `network` tab that how much time and which element take more time to load.